# checkstyle ant task clickable console entry

Tags: checkstyle

I don't know much about eclipse, but one of my juniors asked this.  We use checkstyles to scan our code.  When we get an error, the file that errored shows in the console display.  How do we setup checkstyle and eclipse so that you can click on the class name in the display and go to the file.  An example of what we are seeing

```
[checkstyle] C:\Users\me\Code\RP40\cmcBL\src\main\java\com\foo\bar\client\ProductsDocumentResource.java:98:50: Must have at least one statement.
```

is there a way to make that clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Eclipse-CS](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html), the Checkstyle Eclipse plugin. This will make Checkstyle warnings appear in Eclipse in the 'Problems' view. There, you can click on the entry and it will take you directly to the corresponding line of code.